# video.js WordPress plugin audio only (no video) on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, audio, video, video.js

I'm using the video.js plugin for WordPress, self-hosting the video in WordPress Media Library. Have included .mp4, .webm, and .ogv file formats within shortcode. Have page working well in iOS & OSX (Safari), on OSX with Firefox browser, on iOS with Chrome browser. But nothing I do gets Chrome working on a Mac or PC desktop/laptop. There's the poster and audio, but no video.

```
[videojs mp4="http://wurl.com/assets/IMG_5880.mp4" webm="http://wurl.com/assets/IMG_5880.webmsd.webm" ogv="http://wurl.com/assets/IMG_5880.oggtheora.ogv" poster="http://wurl.com/assets/poster.jpg" height="529" width="940"]
```

Problem post is: http://wurl.com/wurl-hosted-app-running-on-x1-rdk-set-top/

I've searched exhaustively, have saved/resaved/reconverted the files, and still no change. Chrome and WP are up to date.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Not all MP4 files are playable in browsers. You need to make sure you use the h.264 codec.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the video file is saved with the correct encoding and format. Also, compress it so it's not so huge.

*Don't host the video directly on Wordpress CMS*. Upload it to a location manually.

Also, double check the plugin your using. Make sure it's up to date. Has good reviews, and is compatible with your version of Wordpress.